# Change orientation for a single page in a PDF for on screen viewing only

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdftk

I am not sure whether the `pdf` format is capable of this. I think I have seen such files previously but can not find anything definite on this:

Is it possible to rotate some pages in a `pdf` document for **on screen viewing only**?

I do not want this to have any effect on how the document is printed.

I looked at the `pdftk` man page and the closest to a solution I have found is the `rotate` operation, but as far as I understand it, it rotates the page for printing also.

A solution using non-commercial software for linux, like `pdftk`, would be preferable.

Edit:

The use case for me is the following: I'm creating a pdf document (with latex), that I want to provide to a third party in digital form. This document has some pages that contain figures that are sideways, because they are quite wide.

I want that when the third party views my document on screen, the pages with the sideways figures are rotated but when the user prints the document this does not mess up the result. I can not expect that my reader is able or is willing to do any configuration on his part.

Comment: A specific example from you might help to visualize under what situation you might need to do that, but thinking of this at a high level, I could see using Optional Content Groups to have a 2-layer page, one layer defaulting to On and the other defaulting to Off. The difference between the two would be the orientation of the page content: one renders it as Portrait and the other as Landscape (90° or 270° rotation).

As Acrobat or Reader are already capable of rotating the page display, though, I'm not sure what additional problem you're attempting to solve here; sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Added use case above. With what kind of software can I accomplish what you describe?